# Given an integer n, return True if n is within 10 of either 100 or 200

Tags: python, range

Are the two solutions providing the same results to the above question?

```
def almost_there(n):
    return n in range(90,111) or n in range(190,211)
```

```
def almost_there(n):
    return ((abs(100 - n) <= 10) or (abs(200 - n) <= 10))
```

Comment: An automated test might look something like this: `assert all(almost_there1(n) == almost_there2(n) for n in range(1000))` (if you rename the two functions to `almost_there1` and `almost_there2`).

Comment: return 90 <=n<=110 or 190<=n<=200?

Comment: A general approach to independently verify the logic is to use a test. In this case, for example, you can enumerate some N numbers smaller than 90 and verify `almost_there` returns `False` for all, same for numbers great than 210, and so on for the other three ranges..

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide what "equivalent" is. If one is fast and one is slow but they both return the correct answer are they still equivalent?  If one returns different answers than the other for numbers you never expect them to see are they still equivalent? If one is easy to read and the other not are they the same?

```
def at_a(n): return n in range(90,111) or n in range(190,211)
def at_b(n): return ((abs(100 - n) <= 10) or (abs(200 - n) <= 10))
def at_c(n): return (90 <= n <= 110) or (190 <= n <= 210)
                       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit
    setup = "from __main__ import at_a, at_b, at_c"

    print('testing same results for integers between -1000 and 1000.')
    print(f'same?: {all([at_a(n) == at_b(n) == at_c(n) for n in range(-1000,1000)])}')

    print('testing for speed with input = 0.')
    n = 0
    print(f'a: {timeit.timeit("at_a(0)", setup=setup)}')
    print(f'b: {timeit.timeit("at_b(0)", setup=setup)}')
    print(f'c: {timeit.timeit("at_c(0)", setup=setup)}')

    print('testing same results for float inputs between -500 and 500 in 0.5 increments.')
    print(f'all same?: {all([at_a(n/2) == at_b(n/2) == at_c(n/2) for n in range(-1000,1000)])}')
    print(f'a & b same?: {all([at_a(n/2) == at_b(n/2) for n in range(-1000,1000)])}')
    print(f'b & c same?: {all([at_b(n/2) == at_c(n/2) for n in range(-1000,1000)])}')
```

Which gives:

```
testing same results for integers between -1000 and 1000.
same?: True

testing for speed with input = 0.
a: 0.3811636749887839
b: 0.1633004400646314
c: 0.11968454602174461

testing same results for float inputs between -500 and 500 in 0.5 increments.
all same?: False
a & b same?: False
b & c same?: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those two functions are equivalent.  You got the 'tricky' bit of the `range` function, it excludes the end value. Docs are [here](http://def%20almost_there(n):%20%20%20%20%20return%20n%20in%20range(90,111)%20or%20n%20in%20range(190,211)).

In the future, SO is generally not used for confirmation of solutions, it's usually for more open ended questions. Check out the [SO question page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).